# Incorrect sum Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image]In Google sheets I have following formula "=(C1-A1) + (B1-D1)" to get the duration between two times, including a break. I have this in several cells and before I could mark these cells and get the correct sum in the right corner. But now when I mark more than two cells I get an incorrect sum. When I use the formula "sum" I also get the correct sum, but it is different from the sum in the right corner. I have the right format, which is duration so I can't figure out what the issue could be and what have changed since it worked before?[image]

Comment: Those aren't elapsed times, but daily times, so `Mod(10+10+10 , 24)=6`

Comment: @Daniele , do you know what I can do to get the correct sum?

Comment: double check on the format of those times ... they must be duration and not daily times

Comment: @Daniele Oh okay, so everything should be in format duration? Thank you!:)

Comment: @Daniele . Hi again, I changed the times to duration and got the right sum now for total hours. I also have a formula for hours before and after a certain time. In the cells in which I have this formula I have the format duration, but the sum gets wrong still. You can see the formula in the first picture, “Om” means “if”. Do you know what I can do?

Comment: @AnastasiaStojanova I see you have raised a new question with a better image. Suggest that you delete this question.